# Finding the length of a line constructed by coordinates

Tags: distance, graphics

I have a list of coordinates, for example:

```
alist = {{6.51573, 6.93037}, {6.51573, 6.91062}, {6.51573, 6.91062}, {6.51573,
   6.91062}, {6.51573, 6.91062}, {6.47624, 6.91062}, {6.47624, 
  6.87114}, {6.47624, 6.89088}, {6.47624, 6.87114}, {6.47624, 
  6.85139}, {6.47624, 6.85139}, {6.4565, 6.85139}, {6.4565, 
  6.85139}, {6.43675, 6.85139}, {6.43675, 6.85139}, {6.4565, 
  6.85139}, {6.4565, 6.87114}, {6.4565, 6.87114}, {6.4565, 
  6.87114}, {6.4565, 6.87114}, {6.47624, 6.87114}, {6.47624, 
  6.89088}, {6.49599, 6.89088}, {6.49599, 6.89088}, {6.49599, 
  6.89088}, {6.49599, 6.89088}, {6.51573, 6.91062}, {6.51573, 
  6.91062}, {6.51573, 6.89088}, {6.51573, 6.91062}, {6.49599, 
  6.91062}, {6.49599, 6.87114}, {6.47624, 6.85139}, {6.43675, 
  6.83165}, {6.41701, 6.8119}, {6.39726, 6.8119}, {6.37752, 
  6.8119}, {6.35777, 6.83165}, {6.33803, 6.85139}, {6.2788, 
  6.85139}, {6.23931, 6.8119}, {6.18007, 6.73292}, {6.10109, 
  6.67369}, {6.06161, 6.6342}, {6.02212, 6.6342}, {5.8839, 
  6.61446}, {5.80492, 6.59471}, {5.76544, 6.55522}, {5.68646, 
  6.51573}, {5.60748, 6.43675}, {5.5285, 6.39726}, {5.46927, 
  6.33803}, {5.41003, 6.29854}, {5.33105, 6.29854}, {5.25207, 
  6.21956}, {5.19284, 6.18007}, {5.13361, 6.16033}, {5.09412, 
  6.08135}, {5.03488, 5.98263}, {4.95591, 5.8839}, {4.89667, 
  5.84441}, {4.85718, 5.82467}, {4.83744, 5.74569}, {4.81769, 
  5.68646}, {4.7782, 5.60748}, {4.71897, 5.56799}, {4.65974, 
  5.54824}, {4.63999, 5.50876}, {4.62025, 5.46927}, {4.58076, 
  5.44952}, {4.52152, 5.39029}, {4.44254, 5.29156}, {4.4228, 
  5.1731}, {4.32408, 5.07437}, {4.22535, 4.99539}, {4.14638, 
  4.89667}, {4.12663, 4.87693}, {4.10689, 4.73871}, {4.0674, 
  4.63999}, {4.00816, 4.52152}, {3.92918, 4.40306}, {3.85021, 
  4.26484}, {3.83046, 4.16612}, {3.79097, 4.02791}, {3.73174, 
  3.90944}, {3.71199, 3.83046}, {3.63301, 3.71199}, {3.57378, 
  3.57378}, {3.55404, 3.4948}, {3.53429, 3.35659}, {3.45531, 
  3.25787}, {3.39608, 3.11965}, {3.33684, 3.08016}, {3.23812, 
  3.02093}, {3.23812, 2.98144}, {3.25787, 2.92221}, {3.23812, 
  2.86297}, {3.1394, 2.80374}, {3.08016, 2.72476}, {3.06042, 2.66553}}
```

I can see the line using the code

```
ListLinePlot[alist]
```

[image]

and I ask how to find the line length obtained from them.

Comment: In `alist` there are duplicate points! Is this expected?

Comment: Yes, these are real coordinates obtained by time, the same coordinate it means that the object does not move or return to the exact same place. Anyway, thanks for your answer

Comment: If two points are the same for different time, object has moved to the same place I think

Comment: Yes you are right, if between two identical points there are few different points it means that the object moved and returned to the same place (The time differences are 20 msec)

Answer (score 10):

```
RegionMeasure[Line[alist]]
(*6.20188*)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
lcoords = Partition[alist, 2, 1];
Total@(EuclideanDistance @@@ lcoords)
```

> 6.32033

---

**EDIT**

The `alist` starts of at {6.51573, 6.93037} and descends to its final location. The first few points look like this:

```
ListLinePlot[{alist[[1 ;; 40]]}]
```

[image]

and I think `RegionMeasure` is smart enough to discount these knots and double counted regions.

Comment: +1 Compare `Total@(EuclideanDistance @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1]) & /@ {alist, alist // Sort}` with `RegionMeasure[Line[#]] & /@ {alist, alist // Sort}`